# Sample code to explain Banana Monkey Jungle problem by Joe Armstrong

Tags: object-oriented, functional-programming

In the book [**Coders at work**](https://www.codersatwork.com/) Joe Armstrong stated that:

> I think the lack of reusability comes in object oriented
>   languages, not in functional languages. Because the problem with object oriented
>   languages is they’ve got all this implicit environment that they carry
>   around with them. You wanted a banana but what you got was a gorilla
>   holding the banana and the entire jungle

I do not quite get it here. If the problem is to get a banana, we can encapsulate all the logic behind the function 'getBanana'. How are monkey and jungle involved in this context. Could somebody write a code snippet that explains the problem in an easier to understand way, say, demonstrate the fact that the `Banana` object requires the `Monkey` and `Jungle` objects to be initiated, please?

Comment: see [Discuss this ${blog}](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6418/31260)

Comment: Pity this got closed - it was yielding some good discussions. Look into first class functions as a starter.

Comment: @RobbieDee Thats the point. The rules here that no discussion should happen under the question or answers. Discussion should go into chat.

Comment: @Euphoric Discussion type questions [are actually allowed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) but which questions are subjective could be... subjective.

Comment: I believe that this interview was held before Joe Armstrong wrote his PhD thesis. While writing his PhD thesis, Armstrong learned about the *real* definition of OO, and realized that Erlang is actually thoroughly object-oriented, in fact, of all current mainstream languages, Erlang is probably the *most* object-oriented language! He wouldn't have made that statement in that way if he knew that Erlang was actually an OO language. What he is talking about is *ambient authority*, which has absolutely noting whatsoever to do with OO.

Comment: Hi, my question is about providing some sample code that helps me (and others) understand the problem better. Any code snippet that demonstrates the problem is acceptable, not just opinion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He is hinting at a fact, that majority of real OOP programs don't respect separation of concerns. For example, you could have classes:

```
public class Banana
{
    public Monkey Owner {get;}
}

public class Monkey
{
    public Jungle Habitat {get;}
}

public class Jungle
{
}
```

If you use `Banana`, it is transitively necessary to also depend on `Monkey` and `Jungle`.

But I would strictly disagree that this is problem with OOP and that functional style somehow doesn't have it. This can easily be fixed in OOP with introduction of right abstraction.

The problem is more about developers not caring about separation of concerns. And I would not be afraid to assert that majority of OOP programmers are novices, while functional programers have some experience, that motivates them to properly separate their code.

Possible abstraction might be:

```
public class Banana
{
    public IBananaOwner Owner {get;}
}

public interface IBananaOwner
{
}

public class Monkey : IBananaOwner
{
    public Jungle Habitat {get;}
}

public class Jungle
{
}
```

This way, you know that `Banana` has owner, but it doesn't have to be `Monkey`. It can be anything. And it limits what can `Banana` do with owner to only operations defined by `IBananaOwner`, which simplifies reasoning.

Comment: And conversely while functional languages support first class functions out of the box - that isn't to say function X can safely be consumed by function Y without side effects.

Comment: Although you make an excellent point, I think you may be going slightly off piste here. The quote explicitly mentions the *environment* not how the code has been designed.

Comment: @RobbieDee The `Monkey` and `Jungle` are a environment for `Banana`. By introducting abstraction like `IBananaOwner`, the environment becomes explicit. And how this environment is designed is what his problem is all about.

Comment: You may very well be right but I can't help but think having read [this](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2011/07/19/you-wanted-banana/) among other things that the elephant in the room (to add another animal) is that the issue is in correct composition of the functions which functional programming, historically, has lent itself to more.

Comment: @RobbieDee You cannot replace what I written with simple function composition. At least not outside toy example problems. In practice, to fully replace OOP design, things like complex generics, type classes, monads and other are necessary. And that is just changing one kind of complexity for another kind.

Comment: Agreed - it isn't a silver bullet for sure.

Comment: But semantics aside, this is by far the best answer so far +1

Comment: This misses the question. (At least how I interpret the question.) Armstrong is not talking about bad program design. You can write badly designed programs in Erlang, if you want to. Armstrong is talking about *language design*. He is talking about *ambient authority* / *ambient state* / whatever you want to call it. And like many people he assumes "Java == OO", and since Java has ambient authority, and that is a problem, it must be a problem with OO. Well, it's not. Newspeak, for example, is an OO language without ambient authority, that is *much more* OO than Java. In fact, the interesting …

Comment: … thing about Newspeak is that it gets rid of ambient authority *because of being thoroughly OO*! Note that later on Joe Armstrong realized that Erlang is actually OO, more so than Java in fact, so he probably wouldn't have made the statement that way if the interview had been a couple years later.

Comment: @Panzercrisis There is nothing difficult, complicated or leaky in constructing a `Banana`. And there are no encapsulation problems. Also, no consumer of `Banana` needs to know about `IBananaOwner`, as `Banana` can be created elsewhere. `IBananaOwner` is `Banana`'s way of definiting what it expects from it's owner. It is part of `Banana`'s contract.

Comment: I thought I remembered a couple of extra details in the code snippets above that had to do with going from a non-DI approach to a DI approach.  Maybe I thought earlier that it was implied?  Anyway I'll delete my earlier comment.

Comment: @JörgWMittag While Erlang indeed is more 'OO' in the way Alan Kay wanted it to be, it is not the 'OO' that current wide-scale used implementations describe, and also not the kind of 'OO' that the quote refers to.

Comment: The bigger problem is the global dependencies caused by the mutation of state which causes "action at a distance" and code between classes and method calls to depend each other.  The only way to create reusable code is via pure functions on immutable data ala Haskell, Clojure.

Answer (score 18):

[Gorillas are not monkeys!](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-monkeys-apes-and-gorillas)

Leaving that aside, you answer your own question with "*we can encapsulate all the logic behind the function 'getBanana'*". All I want is a banana, but to get it I need to call `getBanana` on some object, eg an instance of the `Gorilla` class. That banana object then likely contains a reference to the gorilla it belongs to and that gorilla object will in turn have a reference to the forest it belongs to. So I ask for a banana, but encapsulated behind that is the entire jungle.

It's an extreme example and won't always be that bad. But it's not uncommon to end up with an OO system like this. And so, to test that `getBanana` method, I need to instantiate, or mock, an entire forest.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question as it has no sample code...